# Socket writing not responding

Tags: java, sockets

I made a simple application to connect a server with a client in java
It does not work

I use new Socket("localhost", 4444); for the client
and new ServerSocket(4444); for the server

Client:
http://www.hastebin.com/siqamonebu.coffee

Server:
http://www.hastebin.com/rivebetani.avrasm

I posted the code on hastebin because its to big to post here
I have no idea what part is broken but the server never receives the message you say

Comment: `I posted the code on hastebin because its to big`. Please read http://sscce.org

Comment: You really think im gonna read that? :P

Comment: @user2107534 You better would. Because most people here will flat out refuse to answer questions that don't withstand the "what have you tried" and "sscce" tests.

Comment: @user2107534 and other users won't be able to read your question at all, sitting behind corporate firewalls preventing access to lots of external sites.

Comment: @beny23 So you think i need to post the whole class in the desc?

Comment: @user2107534: I think you're going to have to bite the bullet and read sscce.org... :-)  If you can't simplify the explanation of your problem, then you might have to post all your code, but be aware some people then take this as a form of laziness, when they see large chunks of code just think "here's someone who says, here's my code, fix it for me, because I don't want to put any effort in" which generally isn't going to convince many people to invest their own spare time...

Comment: Do you really think anybody is going to read all your code at another site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ChatServer - broadcasts to all connected clients

In one command prompt: `java ChartServer`
In another: `java ChatClient localhost` *(or the ip address of where the server is running)*
And another: `java ChatClient localhost` *(or the ip address of where the server is running)*

Start chatting in the client windows.

Server like this...

```
// xagyg wrote this, but you can copy it
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ChatServer {

    public static List list = new ArrayList();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        ServerSocket svr = new ServerSocket(4444);

        System.out.println("Chat Server started!");

        while (true) {
            try {
                Socket s = svr.accept();
                synchronized(list) {
                   list.add(s);              
                }                                  
                new Handler(s, list).start();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                // print out the error, but continue!
                System.err.println(e);
            }
        }
    }
}

class Handler extends Thread {

    private Socket s;
    private String ipaddress;
    private List list;

    Handler (Socket s, List list) throws Exception {
      this.s = s;
      ipaddress = s.getInetAddress().toString();
      this.list = list;
    }

    public void run () {

      try {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
        String message;
        //MyDialog x = (MyDialog)map.get(ipaddress.substring(1));
        while ((message = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (message.equals("quit")) {
                synchronized(list) {
                    list.remove(s);
                }
                break;
            }
            synchronized(list) {
                for (Object object: list) {
                    Socket socket = (Socket)object;
                    if (socket==s) continue;
                    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
                    writer.println(ipaddress + ": " + message);
                    writer.flush();
                }
            }
        }
        try { reader.close(); } catch (Exception e) {}
      }
      catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e);
      }
    }
}
```

Client like this ...

```
// xagyg wrote this, but you can copy it
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class ChatClient {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Socket s = new Socket(args[0], 4444);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String message;
        new SocketReader(in).start();   
        while ((message = reader.readLine())!=null) {
            out.println(message);
            out.flush();
            if (message.equals("quit")) break;
        }
        in.close();
        out.close();
    }        
}

class SocketReader extends Thread {

    BufferedReader in;

    public SocketReader(BufferedReader in) {
        this.in = in;
    }

    public void run() {   
        String message;
        try {
            while ((message = in.readLine())!=null) {
                System.out.println(message);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because how you start your server, try with this structure, since you're cretaing the ServerSocket inside the run method, that could be causing a conflict:

```
public class ThreadSocketServer implements Runnable {

    private int port;
    private boolean isRunning;
    private ServerSocket ss;

    public ThreadSocketServer(int port, boolean initialStatus) {
        this.port = port;
        isRunning = initialStatus;
        System.out.println("Start the server!");
        try {
            ss = new ServerSocket(port);
            Thread threadServer = new Thread(this);
            threadServer.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getClass() + " - " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while (isRunning) {
            try {
                Socket client = ss.accept();

                ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(
                        client.getInputStream());
                //Process here
                ois.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println(e.getClass() + " - " + e.getMessage());
                isRunning = false;
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                System.err.println(e.getClass() + " - " + e.getMessage());
                isRunning = false;
            }
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ThreadSocketServer(1085, true);
    }
```

Comment: mmm... have you tried copy and paste of my code to test it? Then maybe you can adapt your code and replace your logic instead of mine which is inside the try block: Socket client = ... until ois.close().